# How can I build an Underwater base?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, underwater

I have a character who needs to hide some things, I could likely use some magical shenanigans but whats the fun in that when I could have a *lair*!

Instead of going with the conventional cave or underground base I want to do something a bit different, I want to build an underwater base. I have been looking at magic and magic items and the most I've found is some that let me breathe underwater and turn a ship into a sorta submarine like thing.

Is there any support in the rules to build an underwater base that I can come and go from and would be safe enough from underwater monsters? I can use Teleportation to get there and leave so having surface access isn't that important.

Comment: Are you looking to make a lair, base (ie lair for a group) or just an equipment cache to keep things away from greedy (N)PC's?

Comment: @Ifusaso Both I suppose. My character will stay there now and then.

Comment: Sounds like a lich.

Comment: By the way, it´s important to know what kind of spells you have access. Being a 8th level wizard or a 17th level wizards opens several different options.

Comment: *Coughs* Lich where? @ShadowKras I don't see a lich *Puts ear back on* I am lvl 11 right now and I have access to all the item crafting feats up to that level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to build things with magic is to use a whole bunch of castings of spells like *stone shape*, *wall of stone*, *transmute mud to rock*, *disintegrate*, and *wall of iron*.

The other option is to get an earth elemental to build you a base, using one of the *planar ally* spells.  This requires more roleplaying and depends on whether your DM feels like letting you have it.

Building this base underwater will complicate your life, because you'll have to think about how to keep it from flooding.  It's not clear if you would be able to layer *wall of stone*s around your base in a way that would be actually watertight.  You can use *control water* to remove the water when you visit, but it might just seep in again when you leave, and a damp underwater base is not a cozy underwater base.

Comment: Besides, don't forget you'd need to 'pipe in' oxygen or else hold your breath per suffocation rules...

Comment: Reading comments on the above, OP may or may not be a lich (and thus not need to breathe).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the answers Dan suggested, You can always go the more mundane route. Of course you would need water breathing, but you can always have the building materials shipped over via boat, dumped into the ocean, then dive down and manual labor the base into construction.

Once you have a watertight building pumping water out of it would probably require a control water spell. Keeping it dry and breathable is another story. You would ether need an Airlock (and [decompression chamber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompression_sickness) depending on how much of a stickler your DM is for science -- decompression sickness can kill you!) or a selective barrier custom enchantment, (likely of the Evocation (force) or Abjuration schools)

And finally of course a way to get breathable air, again, enchantments for air bubble or other air spells are the easiest route.

Comment: Decompression chambers are a factor of how the station is pressurized.  Modern seabases are sometimes kept at ambient local sea pressure, without a need for a decompression chamber on the base.  Of course, getting back and forth to the surface would prove a challenge, but that's not going to factor into construction in the slightest for that type of seabase.

Comment: Still may be a good thing to have if you are going to have teleportation to and from your base. Since it is underwater and likely in the middle of an ocean, depending on if you want a dock or ship above it at any given time, (and if I were a lich and trying to hide my phylactery, I wouldn't) it may not be a bad thing to include.